# Dual of generalized Reed-Solomon code

Tags: combinatorics, cryptography, coding-theory

I need to show that $GRS_{n,k}(\alpha,\mathbb{1})^{\perp}=GRS_{n,n-k}(\alpha,\alpha)$, where $\alpha=(1,a,\ldots,a^{n-1})$, $a$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, $\mathbb{1}=(1,1,\ldots,1)$.

So, to show this, I think It suffices to show that $c\cdot c'=0$ for all $c\in GRS_{n,k}(\alpha,\mathbb{1})$ and for all $c'\in GRS_{n,n-k}(\alpha,\alpha)$. I am kinda stuck how to approach this, should I go with the generating matrix or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly

$$c=(1\cdot f(1),1 \cdot f(a),1\cdot f(a^2),\cdots,1\cdot f(a^{n-1}))=(f(1),f(a),f(a^2),\cdots, f(a^{n-1})),$$
and
$$c'=(1\cdot g(1),a \cdot g(a),a^2\cdot g(a^2),\cdots,a^{n-1}\cdot g(a^{n-1}))=(g(1),ag(a),a^2g(a^2),\cdots, a^{n-1}g(a^{n-1})).$$
Where $f$ has degree at most $k-1$ and $g$ has degree at most $n-k-1.$

So the product has degree at most $n-2.$ One then needs to show that the product is actually the zero polynomial, using Lagrange interpolation. You can refer to John Hall's very useful Coding Theory [notes](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/jhall/classes/codenotes/GRS.pdf) (Chapter 5) at Michigan State, if you need more details.

Comment: I have looked at those before, the thing is that I do not know how to derive the inverses. I have no information in my problem what they are